# How to fix a wrong/incomplete typescript definition?

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I am using `mongo@4.2.1`. In this package the `openUploadStreamWithId` in the `GridFSBucket` is defined as `ObjectId`.

**mongodb.d.ts**

```
export declare class GridFSBucket extends TypedEventEmitter<GridFSBucketEvents> {
    ...
    openUploadStreamWithId(id: ObjectId, filename: string, options?: GridFSBucketWriteStreamOptions): GridFSBucketWriteStream;
    ...
}
```

But it should be `type GridFSBucketWriteStreamId = string | number | Object | ObjectID;` [stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/200108) [mongodb driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/api/GridFSBucket.html#openUploadStreamWithId)

I'm using a string as id, instead of an ObjectId, therefore I have to fix the definition.

How can I extend the `openUploadStreamWithId` typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why don't you just create an ObjectID from your string?

Anyway, let's say you have this

```
const myStringID = '5783878927082'
```

Instead of messing with the types, just do the good ol' `unknown` trick:

```
openUploadStreamWithId(myStringID as unknown as ObjectID, ...)
```

This will stop the compiler complaining, but you better know what you're doing.

Comment: I'm using `nanoid` for the _id-value instead of ObjectIds, but obviously the driver v4+ removed the typing for string values. Now only ObjectIds are handled correctly.